# Me entra continuamente en el if

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un conecta 4 y estoy tratando de que entre en el color azul (jugador1) y color rojo (jugador2), y lo quiero hacer mediante un boolean. La cosa es, que como hago bajar las fichas, cada rotación de ficha me cambia de color y la idea es que hasta no se haga el click no cambie de color. ¿Alguna idea? He probado fors, whiles... pero no hay manera.

```
let q = false;

function gravedad(arrayCeldas, fila){
    
    if(fila < arrayCeldas.length && !arrayCeldas[fila].classList.contains("jugador1") && q===true){
        if (fila>0){
            filaAnterior = fila-1;
            arrayCeldas[filaAnterior].classList.remove('jugador1');
        }
        arrayCeldas[fila].classList.add('jugador1');
        setTimeout(function(){
            gravedad(arrayCeldas, fila+1);
        }, 500); 
        q=false;
    } 

    else if(fila < arrayCeldas.length && !arrayCeldas[fila].classList.contains("jugador2") && q ===false){
        if (fila>0){
            filaAnterior = fila-1;
            arrayCeldas[filaAnterior].classList.remove('jugador2');
            
        }
        arrayCeldas[fila].classList.add('jugador2');
        setTimeout(function(){
            gravedad(arrayCeldas, fila+1);
        }, 500);
    }
    q=true;

    
}
```

Comment: Podés agregar un snippet en la pregunta (con el botón que indica `<>`) para agregar un [repro] en la pregunta misma. Por cierto, leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Al final de la función tienes `q=true` (que no está claro qué es ni se ve en ninguna otra zona del código), por lo que la próxima vez que pases por la misma función (si no lo cambias en otro sitio), el `else if` no se cumplirá, ¿no?

Comment: la linea q=true debería ir dentro del else if, si no siempre q va a ser true